# Is it possible to use reflection to examine a function's decorators in Python 2.5?

Tags: python

This is what i want to do:

```
@MyDecorator
def f():
   pass

for d in f.decorators:
   print d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not generally possible without the cooperation of the decorators. For example,

```
def my_decorator(f):
     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
         return f(*args, **kwargs)
     wrapper.decorators = [wrapper]
     if hasattr(f, 'decorators'):
         wrapper.decorators.extend[f.decorators]
     return wrapper
```

Essentially, all the decorator does is wrap the function as usual and then put a decorators attribute on the wrapper function. It then checks the wrapped function for a similar list and propagates it upwards.

This is pretty useless though

What I *think* you want is

```
def my_decorator(f):
       def wrapper(args):
           return f(args)
      wrapper.decorated = f
      return wrapper
```

This will allow you to do stuff like

```
@my_other_decorator # another decorator following the same pattern
@my_decorator
def foo(args):
    print args

foo.decorated(args) # calls the function with the inner decorated function (my_decorator)
foo.decorated.decorated(args) # original function
```

You can actually abstract this pattern into a decorator

```
def reversable(decorator):
    def wrapper(func):
        ret = decorator(func) # manually apply the decorator
        ret.decorated = func # save the original function
        return ret
    return wrapper
```

Now when you are writing your decorator:

```
@reversable
def my_decorator(f):
    def wrapper(x):
        return f(x + 1)
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Note that Python 3.2's `functools.wraps` uses the name `__wrapped__` to point to the original function.  I recommend using the same name, so code can stop diverging on this.  (I need to start doing this, too; I've always used the name "func".)  I'd recommend actually using `functools.wraps`, but that's not much of a solution until 3.2 is actually in wide use.

Answer (score 1):

The `@MyDecorator` syntax is just shorthand for writing the following Python code:

```
def f():
  pass
f = MyDecorator(f)
```

Written in this form, you can see that the decorators applied to the function are not kept track of in any way. You *could* make your decorators remember when they're applied [(Aaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929317/is-it-possible-to-use-reflection-to-examine-a-functions-decorators-in-python-2-5/3929337#3929337) has a couple good ideas on how to do this), but you'd have to wrap all third-party decorators with your own.